# Catchable Fatal Error in symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony

" Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class My\AlphabusBundle\Entity\Clients could not be converted to string "

I have a table that is called `chassis` with primary key `nchassis` and other table `Clients` with primary key `Id`.
I created another table which is called `assignment` which I must insert the first key of the `Chassis` table and the `Client` Table as 2 key foreign
in the new table to assign a customer to a chassis well give but a problem was shown message and Id must always integer

Comment: add a __toSring() magic method to your client entity

Answer (score 0):

implement the function __toString() in Clients Entity .
For example :

```
  function __toString() {
     return $this->getName();
  }
```

Comment: Id is integer , the rest of the entity is of type string